# Can someone else help in making a descion about a hand

Tags: cheating

Is it ok for another player, out of a hand, help another player in a hand and make a decision?

Comment: Depends on the "seriousness" of the game. Most hosts will require players who have folded to shut up

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. The standard rule is "one player per hand".